# Inclusion about solution of inequality

Tags: inequality

Lets consider the following inequality form [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861257/is-there-any-clever-way-to-solve-inequalities-like-y2-y-2-geq-4-y2y-2?noredirect=1#comment3812097_1861257):

$$|y^2-y-2|\geq 4 + |y^2+y-2|+|y+4|+|y|$$

User Did said that:

$$ |y^2-y-2|=|4+(y^2+y-2)-(y+4)-y|.$$

Using the triangular inequality implies:

$$ |y^2-y-2|\leq 4 + |y^2+y-2|+|y+4|+|y|.$$

User Did then concludes:

> ... the only way the desired inequality can hold is when it is an **equality**
>   and **every term involved has the same sign**.

My question: The first part about the equality I can comprehend. But why should all terms that are involved have the same sign?

Comment: To be rigorous, you also need to consider the case when any of the term involved is zero.  Besides that, one way to see that is by considering the case for two numbers: $|x+y|<=|x|+|y|$ and the equality holds iff $xy\ge 0$.  You can then apply it repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you alot. Such a simple explanation. Thank you alot :).